# oracle forms - how to evaluate a text item for a decimal value

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

How to evaluate a text item for a decimal value ? I just need to produce a msg_alert if the user enters a decimal value ?

Comment: Something like `instr( to_char( :YOUR_FIELD ), '.' ) > 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
IF instr( :YOUR_FIELD, '.' ) > 0 THEN
    msg_alert('blah blah');
END IF;
```

Or if you are dealing with a numeric field you may need to cast to a string first

```
IF instr( to_char( :YOUR_FIELD ), '.' ) > 0 THEN
    msg_alert('blah blah');
END IF;
```

Comment: I tried the above piece of code in the item- level - trigger , but it doesn't fire , but rather throws the usual form error FRM-50006 - Legal character error . The item is of integer datatype .

Comment: If it's an integer datatype, then how can you enter a `.`? Maybe this is the cause of the error, you are trying to treat an integer field as something else. You could try changing the datatype of the field to allow the validation to work the way you want (seems pointless - no pun intended). Or, you could try to trap the error and do something with it.

Comment: I just want to throw a customized error message rather than a form error.